WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed:
When I try to run this code on browser it display buttons but when I click on the button "WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed: " error throws. My server file has following code
const express = require('express');
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;






app.use(express.json());

const pool = new Pool({
user: 'user',
host: 'db',
database: 'mydatabase',
password: 'password',
port: 5432,
});

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});

app.get('/api/hello/french', (req, res) => {
res.json({ message: 'Bonjour le monde' });
});

app.post('/api/user', async (req, res) => {
const { name } = req.body;
const client = await pool.connect();
try {
await client.query('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ($1)', [name]);
res.status(201).send('Name saved');
} finally {
client.release();
}
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

my app.js has following code
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
const [name, setName] = useState('');

const handleEnglishClick = async () => {
try {
  console.log('Fetching English message...');
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/hello');
  console.log('Response:', response);
  setMessage(response.data.message);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching English message:', error);
}
};

const handleFrenchClick = async () => {
 try {
  console.log('Fetching French message...');
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/hello/french');
  console.log('Response:', response);
  setMessage(response.data.message);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching French message:', error);
}
};

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
try {
  console.log('Saving name...');
  await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/user', { name });
  alert('Name saved');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error saving name:', error);
}
};

return (
  <div>

  <h1>{message}</h1>
  <h2>this is output panel</h2>
  <button onClick={handleEnglishClick}>English</button>
  <button onClick={handleFrenchClick}>French</button>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={name}
      onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      placeholder="Enter your name"
    />
    <button type="submit">Save Name</button>
  </form>
</div>
 );
 }

export default App;

my dockerfile has folowing code
version: '3.8'

services:
db:
image: postgres:latest
restart: always
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
networks:
  - mynetwork

web:
build: .
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
depends_on:
  - db
networks:
  - mynetwork

client:
build:
  context: ./client
ports:
  - "3001:3000"
depends_on:
  - web
environment:
  - REACT_APP_API_URL=http://web:3000/api
networks:
  - mynetwork

networks:
mynetwork:

Please help me in this issue.

It looks like your server-side handler code is trying to call localhost; in this context, that will be the specific container running that code.  If the code you quote is in the client container and the Websocket server is in the web container, the client container call to localhost calls itself and not the other container.  There is another case here where REACT_APP_API_URL needs to be set differently: the code that actually runs in the end user's browser (the React app proper) can't see the Docker-network hostnames.
